# Ubuntu Add static routing for local addresses

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am using Ubuntu at work and connect to VPN to reach the servers of the company. The VPN connection should be always on in order to work properly. However sometimes I need to communicate with other local machines which I can't communicate when connected to VPN. So, I need a solution for this. I think I need to add static routing for the local IP addresses. But I could not find how can I apply static routing for my case. Is there anyone could help me about routing.

Details:
I need to reach 192.168.1.x addresses when VPN is connected.

ifconfig result when VPN conected:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:ee:75:7c:d6:97  
      inet addr:192.168.1.211  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::56ee:75ff:fe7c:d697/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:101630 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:32820 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:58166203 (58.1 MB)  TX bytes:5624100 (5.6 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f2a00000-f2a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:104042 (104.0 KB)  TX bytes:104042 (104.0 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.55.96  P-t-P:192.168.55.96  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1412  Metric:1
          RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:57 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:1545 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:3412 (3.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a temporary static route, use:

```
sudo ip route add <network>/<mask> dev <device>
```

e.g.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

To add a persistent static route, use the `nmcli` command:

```
nmcli device modify <device> ipv4.routes "<network>/<mask> <gateway>" ipv4.route-metric 25
```

e.g.

```
nmcli device modify eth0 ipv4.routes "192.168.1.0/24 192.168.1.254" ipv4.route-metric 25
```

and then restart the NetworkManager service:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a temporary static route, use:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

or

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0
```

To add permanent static route in ubuntu 18.04 and newers, add below line at the end of file:

```
# vi /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
  network:
    ethernets:
      eth0:
        dhcp4: false
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.100/24
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
          addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
          - 8.8.8.8
        routes:
        - to: 192.168.1.0/24
          via: 192.168.1.1
    version: 2
# netplan apply
```

in older than ubuntu 18.04, just add below line to the end of the below file:

```
# vi /etc/network/interfaces
  up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
  up ip route add 172.16.0.0/16 via 172.16.1.1 dev ens33
```